# Div containers not in Order

Tags: html, css

I have 4 div containers in same horizontal row.

```
This is how I defined them.
<center>
<div id="chart_div" style="float:left; width:25%; display:inline;"></div>
<div id="chart_div2" style="float:right; width:25%; display:inline;"></div>
<div id="chart_div3" style="float:left; width:25% ; display:inline;"></div>
 <div id="chart_div4" style="float:right; width:25% ; display:inline;"></div>
</center>
```

These appear in same row but not in order I defined.

`chart_div :` on extreme left
`chart_div2:` on extreme right
`chart_di3:` In middle left
`chart_div4:` In middle right

How do I fix this ?

Comment: You can `float` all the `div` to `left` that works

Comment: first thing is `center` tag is Deprecated in HTML5. and if you want to align all div in same  line. you can use `float:left` or `display:inline-block`. Use them wisely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine here. Can you please tell me if you've used `padding` / `margin` / `border` there?

```html
<center>
<div id="chart_div" style="float:left; width:25%; background: #666">left</div>
<div id="chart_div2" style="float:right; width:25%; background: #ccc">Right</div>
<div id="chart_div3" style="float:left; width:25% ; background: #666">left</div>
 <div id="chart_div4" style="float:right; width:25% ; background: #ccc">Right</div>
</center>
```